# upgrade/downgrade Kernel CentOS to a different version than the last one, and different version than the previously used locally

Tags: centos, kernel, upgrade

I would like to Upgrade/downgrade Kernel CentOS to a different version than the last one, and then downgrade to a different version than the previously used locally.

First, I installed `CentOS 8.1 (8.1.1911)` with kernel version 4.18.0-147, later I made a upgrade to `Centos 8.2 (8.2.2004)` with kernel version `4.18.0-193`.

Now, I want to test if certain packages/rpms work with certain kernel versions

1. I would like to upgrade to Kernel version `5.6.19`
2. to make a downgrade to Kernel version `5.5.19`
3. I want to go back to my current kernel version `4.18.0-193`.

The Upgrade and Downgrade steps is because I am not sure which version could serve me, so I need to know how to do it without having them previously installed.

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:38 ago on Fri 03 Jul 2020 09:52:52 PM -05.
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Architecture                               Version                                                  Repository                                         Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel-ml                                             x86_64                                     5.7.7-1.el8.elrepo                                       elrepo-kernel                                      32 k
Installing dependencies:
 kernel-ml-core                                        x86_64                                     5.7.7-1.el8.elrepo                                       elrepo-kernel                                      28 M
 kernel-ml-modules                                     x86_64                                     5.7.7-1.el8.elrepo                                       elrepo-kernel                                      23 M

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  3 Packages

Total download size: 51 M
Installed size: 87 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

`5.6.19` or `5.5.19` aren't listed!

```
$ sudo yum install kernel-ml-5.6.19
Last metadata expiration check: 1 day, 2:50:13 ago on Thu 02 Jul 2020 07:05:24 PM -05.
No match for argument: kernel-ml-5.6.19
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-ml-5.6.19
$

$ sudo yum install kernel-5.6.19
Last metadata expiration check: 1 day, 2:53:29 ago on Thu 02 Jul 2020 07:05:24 PM -05.
No match for argument: kernel-5.6.19
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-5.6.19
$
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why didn't you press Y for `"sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml"` and then proceeded to install a package which doesn't exist ?

Comment: As yo can see the version that I looking for I can't get.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  Yes! The version are `5.6.19` or `5.5.19`

Comment: Old kernel versions take a lot of space and normally people try to avoid having an archive of all of them. If you had enabled this repo if a few months ago, you could have installed kernel 5.5.x as well. Now your only simple option are to compile it from sources or start looking for RPMs.

Comment: Thanks, is there another option?

Comment: You could compile the source.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo yum list --showduplicates|grep kernel-ml`

Answer (score 1):

The kernel package in Linux distros is **not** tied to the userland which means you're free to install as many kernels as you want and boot into any of them.

So, forget about "upgrading" and "downgrading". Think about "installing" and "removing" kernel packages.

If you want to install mainline stable kernels in CentOS please enable this repo: https://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml

Comment: Thank you, But I was trying to install another version and I can't.